# Sony Camera API to set the meta tags from the Android App

Tags: android, api, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am using the Android SDK for Sony Camera and its working fine, and wanted to send additional settings from App to camera image to Adding meta tags like Author, Tags or even GPS coordinates.

My Question

1. Is there any way to send additional parameter settings to the Camera pictures.
2. Alternatively Can I get the copy of the recent picture to Mobile App and changes these.

Answer (score 0):

There's no availability within the API to send that kind of meta data to the camera.

Therefore you would have to get a copy of the picture to the phone, and put the meta data on the image within your app.

Comment: Actually I am unable to retrieve the copy of the image to Phone using that API too.